# ASP.Net Authorization Programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have multiple `IHttpHandler` in project. I have register those handler to RouteCollection to get trigger on specific URL.

I wanted some handler to be authorized using programmatically. I do not want to use below setting in my `web.config`. I can't use `[Authorize]` attribute because it's not using Controller as we see in asp.net MVC.

```xml
<system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Current project doesn't use `System.Web.Mvc` anywhere.

It's using [System.Web.Routing.Route()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.routing.route?view=netframework-4.8#examples) to register route info using custom created class `GenericRouteHandler:IRouteHandler`that return [IHttpHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ihttphandler?view=netframework-4.8). That Handler example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ihttphandler.processrequest?view=netframework-4.8#examples

Comment: Hook into the `Authenticate` event in `global.asax` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.windowsauthenticationmodule.authenticate?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @kshkarin How can i trigger that request to be authenticated? I am using  `OpenIdConnectAuthentication`.

Comment: have you tried the ```Authenticate``` method in ```global.asax``` ? The asp.net pipeline should call it for authentication, set a breakpoint there

Comment: their documentation mentions `Application_AuthenticateRequest` which is also part of the pipeline and can be hooked into from `global.asax` https://libraries.io/nuget/OpenId.AspNet.Authentication#typical-wiring

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this would help in old MVC but this is the way you can do it in AspNetCore middleware.

Basically you return 401 handshake on request that is not authorized and the MVC pipeline should authenticate for you. The next time you check if user is auth'ed and skip the handshake if he is or request auth if previous failed.

I do this in a middleware that intercepts the request before it gets to a controller.

```
if (context.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated != true)
{
    context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
    context.Response.Headers.Add("www-authenticate", new StringValues(new[] { "Negotiate", "NTLM" }));
    await context.Response.CompleteAsync();
}
```

Old MVC should be similar I think but your mileage may vary.

Comment: Current project doesn't even use `System.Web.Mvc` anywhere. 

It's using `System.Web.Routing.Route()` to register `IRouteHandler` that return `IHttpHandler`. I have updated my questions with some more information.

Answer (score 0):

Using the ASP.NET pipeline it's possible to hook into `Authenticate` events in `global.asax`, per the question [OpenID documentation](https://libraries.io/nuget/OpenId.AspNet.Authentication#typical-wiring) shows how to authenticate in the `Authenticate_Request` event, pasted here for clarity:

```
//file: Global.asax.cs
...
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenIdAuthentication.Authenticate();
}
```

Comment: Project currently using Owin setup. It's using this middleware https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn782620(v=vs.113) to setup openId. I am not sure what method I should call under `Application_AuthenticateRequest` to trigger openId authentication.

Comment: just to make sure - the project does have a `global.asax` and you've added the `AuthenticateRequest` method correct? If that's the case then simply call `Authenticate` just like in the documentation

Comment: Yes, there is `global.asax` file in project. In order to add `Authenticate` method, I have to use that NuGet and setup the openId you suggested. In my case there is already openId setup using Owin middleware `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions`.

Comment: @dev ok and does it hit the break point inside the `AuthenticateRequest` method when debugging?

Comment: yes it does inside `global.asax` file. Just not sure what method i should call to trigger openId authentication.

Comment: @dev that's good, just to be sure is this self hosted or still on IIS? And is there an `<authentication>` node in web.config under `<system.web>` if so what is the value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222802/discussion-between-kshkarin-and-dev).

Comment: I am still not able to trigger the login page.